# AutoCompleteTextview with Textwatcher android

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, addtextchangedlistener

I have a small issue with **AutoCompleteTextview** with
**textwatcher**.

I Have **AutoCompleteTextview** for Suggestion.The data Comes From API side. With every new word I write in,  API is being called and, it gets Response from ApI side and then, The show Dropdown menu for suggestion is shown.So basically that code is in **AddTextWatcher** Listener.

But when I click on Particular Suggestion, the **AddTextwatcher** is being Call and it recalls the ApI and  the suggestions are shown again!So it is like

-**Write in AutoCompleteTextview >> Api is being Called >> Fill in the Data >> Show Suggestions >> and Click On Suggestion >> Show Suggestions again.**

Help me with this particular problem.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: its not good solution @pskink

Comment: Isn't there a way to catch the click? Subclass AutoCompleteTextView,  overwrite the Event, don't call the TextWatcher if he clicked? As soon as you know the user clicked, you can assume he chose a suggestion and doesn't want do get another one, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Decclare variable :

   ```
    private var textWatcher : TextWatcher? = null
    private var selectedItemId: String? = null
   ```
2. Initialize the declared variable and apply text watcher as :

   textWatcher =  object : TextWatcher {
   override fun afterTextChanged(char: Editable?) { }

   ```
        override fun beforeTextChanged(char: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}

        override fun onTextChanged(char: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            if(selectedItemId!=null){
                return
            }
            callApi()
        }
    }
   ```
3. When the response is received from API :

   val adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireActivity(),
   R.layout.custom_spinner_item, R.id.item_text_view, itemList!!)
   mBinding.AutoCompleteTextview.setAdapter(adapter )

   ```
        mBinding.AutoCompleteTextview.error = null
        mBinding.AutoCompleteTextview.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
        mBinding.AutoCompleteTextview.showDropDown()


    mBinding.AutoCompleteTextview.setOnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, position, l ->

        selectedItemId = adapter.getItem(position)!!.id!!.toString()
        mBinding.AutoCompleteTextview.clearFocus()

    }
   ```
4. Final step :

   mBinding.AutoCompleteTextview.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, b ->
   if (b){
   mBinding.AutoCompleteTextview.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
   }
   }